# Wordpress: Contact form 7 select form getting array from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, custom-post-type, contact-form-7

I'm setting up a site where a friend of mine can create new color pattern for her shop, but I would like to link it to a contact order form. 
Currently, she has to create them both in the custom fields I set up AND in the contact form.
example: She create the color red for people to choose, but then she has to type 'red' in the select tag of contact form 7. "farve" = "color" (in danish) ;)

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Color</label>
[select* menu-farve class:form-control "red" "blue"]
```

Now I have the custom post type slug called. "color", but 
 **how do I create an array that I can impliment into the form?** 
 **and how to I get it into the form?**
I have an array to display the color name from my custom post type if that helps:

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'color' );
        $posts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
        $image = get_field('color_image', $post->ID);
            setup_postdata( $post ); 
            if ( get_field( 'sold' ) ): ; else: ?>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src=" <?php echo $image['url'] ?> ">
                        <h2 class="">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php endforeach;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish dynamically generating Contact Form 7 selects.

**Option 1: PHP**

A great solution found both on the [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115947/contact-form-7-populate-select-list-with-taxonomy) and a blog by [Lee Willis](https://www.leewillis.co.uk/dynamic-select-list-contact-form-7/) with the following being from the StackExchange as follows:

```php
/** Dynamic List for Contact Form 7 **/
/** Usage: [select name term:taxonomy_name] **/
function dynamic_select_list($tag, $unused){ 
    $options = (array)$tag['options'];
foreach ($options as $option) 
    if (preg_match('%^term:([-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$%', $option, $matches)) 
        $term = $matches[1];

//check if post_type is set
if(!isset($term))
    return $tag;

$taxonomy = get_terms($term, array('hide_empty' => 0));

if (!$taxonomy)  
    return $tag;

foreach ($taxonomy as $cat) {  
    $tag['raw_values'][] = $cat->name;  
    $tag['values'][] = $cat->name;  
    $tag['labels'][] = $cat->name;
}

$tag['raw_values'][] = 'Other';  
$tag['values'][] = 'Other';  
$tag['labels'][] = 'Other - Please Specify Below';

return $tag; 
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'dynamic_select_list', 10, 2);
```

This is for taxonomies but can be edited to use the the array you provided as follows

```
    $options = (array) $tag[‘options’];
foreach ( $options as $option ) {
    if ( preg_match( ‘%^posttype:([-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$%’, $option, $matches ) )
{
        $post_type = $matches[1];
    }
}
//check if post_type is set
if(!isset($post_type))
    return $tag;


$args= array(
    'post_type' => $post_type
);
$colors = get_posts($args);

if ( ! $colors )
        return $tag;

foreach ( $colors as $color ) {  
        $tag['raw_values'][] = $color->post_title;  
        $tag['values'][] = $color->post_title;  
        $tag['labels'][] = $color->post_title;   
    }  

    return $tag;  
}
```

**Option 2: Plugin**

The [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) may have the functionality you're seeking.

Comment: I figured that you add it in the additional settings, but how do I get it into the select?
[select* color posttype:color] would this do it?

Comment: I found my solution somewhere else, but the code is almost the same:

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution somewhere else, but the code is almost the same

```
function dynamic_field_values ( $tag, $unused ) {

    if ( $tag['name'] != 'colorfield' )
        return $tag;

    $args = array (
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'color',
        'orderby'       => 'title',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
    );

    $custom_posts = get_posts($args);

    if ( ! $custom_posts )
        return $tag;

    foreach ( $custom_posts as $custom_post ) {
        $tag['raw_values'][] = $custom_post->post_title;
        $tag['values'][] = $custom_post->post_title;
        $tag['labels'][] = $custom_post->post_title;
    }

    return $tag;

}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'dynamic_field_values', 10, 2);
```